# Ошибка "Cannot find CharacterClass in java.lang.Character"

Tags: java, импорт

Столкнулся с ошибкой при наследовании. Всё проходит хорошо, пока классы находятся в одном пакете.

Но при попытке наследовать из другого пакета, IDE ставит перед названием класса название пакета (в котором лежит этот класс) и точку, выдавая следом ошибку.

Я не знаю как это победить, я погуглил и внятного ответа не нашёл.

Класс CharacterClass:

```java
package Character;

public class CharacterClass {
    ...
}
```

Класс Warrior:

```java
package Players;

public class Warrior extends Character.CharacterClass {
    ...
}
```

Я понимаю что проблема в точке между Character и CharacterClass, но что делать, я не знаю.

**UPD:** заметил что не подключается import. Хотя в настройках подключен автоматический.

**Ошибка**:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'CharacterClass' java: cannot find symbol symbol: class CharacterClass location: class java.lang.Character

Comment: Вы задаете имя пакета явно в начале файла? У вас  java файл должен начинаться с имени пакета которому принадлежит

Comment: Какого рода ошибка у вас возникает?  Ошибка компиляции из-за отсутствия `import`'?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'CharacterClass'
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CharacterClass
  location: class java.lang.Character

Comment: Покажите в вопросе, какие импорты у вас написаны в классe `Warrior`.

Comment: Вы называете пакеты с большой буквы, тем самым поставили джаву в тупик. Не называйте пакеты с большой буквы. Имя `Character` это класс, который импортируется автоматически из `java.lang`. Назовите пакет хотя бы `character`, а еще лучше — `org.example.app.character`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По соглашению, имя пакета [следует называть](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) в соответствии с названием вашей организации. Например, если ваша организация владеет доменом `example.org`, то все ваши пакеты должны находится в пакете `org.example` (имя домена записывается в обратном порядке).

Например, ваш пакет `players` для программы `app` будет лежать в:

```
package org.example.app.players;
```

Следование этим правилам позволит вам избежать указанной в вопросе ошибки.

Ваша ошибка связана с тем, что у вас не получается правильно импортировать класс из пакета `Character`, потому что в java есть класс с таким названием: `Character`.

Класс `Character` находится в пакете `java.lang`, который импортируется автоматически.

Comment: Моя благодарность,  изменил имя пакета и теперь все работает. Постараюсь быть внимательнее к таким вещам.